# How to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}=\infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, indeterminate-forms

Let's say I need to find the limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}$$
So I know that the limit is $\infty$, but I'm not sure how to show it in situations like this.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right)^n=e^{\infty}=\infty$$
I'm pretty sure this one is wrong, because I can't just have the power of infinity. How do I write it down properly?

Also, is $\lim_{n\to\infty}1^n=1$? I know I can't just write $\lim_{n\to\infty}1^n=1^{\infty}$, how should I do it properly?

Comment: I'd accept that just fine. However, you could take the $\log$ then do the limit then re-exponentiate to get the solution.

Comment: Re the question at the end: $\lim_{n\to\infty}1^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}1=1$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recall that for $a > 0$ and $m > 1$, we have
$$(1+a)^m > 1+ma \tag{$\star$}$$
The proof for $(\star)$ follows immediately from Binomial theorem.
Hence, in your case, we have
$$\left(1+\dfrac1n\right)^{n^2} > 1 + \dfrac{n^2}n = 1 +n$$
Now conclude what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
Since $\lim\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e>2$ it follows that for large $n, \ \left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n^2}>2^n$.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the limit of $(1+\frac 1n)^n$ and how to derive it, you ought to be able to show that if $n$ is large enough, $(1+\frac 1n)^n\gt a \gt 1$ so for $n$ large enough $(1+\frac 1n)^{n^2}=\left((1+\frac 1n)^n\right)^n\gt a^n$

I'll leave the gaps for you to fill in.